# Ошибка: "Use of unassigned local variable"

Tags: c#

Привет всем, скажите, что делать, когда такая ошибка при компиляции

> `Error 3   Use of unassigned local variable 'username'`

```
private void btnMoan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cnt = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
        try
        {
            cnt.Open();
            cmd = cnt.CreateCommand();

            string username;

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO t_banned(URL, user_id) VALUES ('" + URL + "','" + username + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Жалоба добавлена", "Системное соощение");
        }
        catch (MySqlException ee)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: При компиляции любого кода или только какого то конкретного?

Comment: Всего кода, там в одном событии объявил переменную, и только из-за этого не компилируется.

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы вы привели какие-то выдержки из кода, скажем, код этого события и место, где эта ошибка возникает.

Comment: Код в студию)

Comment: Вот здесь ошибка: 
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO t_banned(URL, user_id) VALUES ('" + URL + "','" + username + "'";

Answer (score 1):

Исправьте на:

```
string username = string.Empty;
```

Comment: А можете сказать, что делает Empty?

Comment: Ваша переменная равна НУЛЛ, небходимо ее инициализировать. Empty - ето просто пустая строка - еквивалент: ""

Comment: Спасибо проблемма решена.